# Port -v self update can't find cc

Tags: port

MBP (10.7.3) Xcode 4.3.1 works, it compiles a c program.

ran sudo port -v selfupdate
BELOW is part of the console.log

```
configure:2735: result: i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
configure:2763: checking MacPorts version
configure:2766: result: 2.0.4
configure:2799: checking for sw_vers
configure:2817: found /usr/bin/sw_vers
configure:2829: result: /usr/bin/sw_vers
configure:2839: checking for defaults
configure:2857: found /usr/bin/defaults
configure:2869: result: /usr/bin/defaults
configure:2879: checking for xcode-select
configure:2897: found /usr/bin/xcode-select
configure:2909: result: /usr/bin/xcode-select
configure:2919: checking Mac OS X version
configure:2922: result: 10.7.3
configure:2945: checking Xcode location
configure:2948: result: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
configure:3036: checking for gcc
configure:3063: result: /usr/bin/cc
configure:3292: checking for C compiler version
configure:3301: /usr/bin/cc --version >&5
./configure: line 3303: /usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
configure:3312: $? = 127
configure:3301: /usr/bin/cc -v >&5
./configure: line 3303: /usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
configure:3312: $? = 127
configure:3301: /usr/bin/cc -V >&5
./configure: line 3303: /usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
configure:3312: $? = 127
configure:3301: /usr/bin/cc -qversion >&5
./configure: line 3303: /usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
configure:3312: $? = 127
configure:3332: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3354: /usr/bin/cc    conftest.c  >&5
./configure: line 3356: /usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
configure:3358: $? = 127
configure:3396: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "MacPorts"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "macports"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.0.4"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "MacPorts 2.0.4"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "macports-dev@lists.macosforge.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3401: error: in `/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/base':
configure:3403: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

What do I need to do? Xcode is linked to the C compiler and port knows the Xcode location.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What language is this? Where is this run? Please edit your question and tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode doesn't install all the command line tools by default, and even if you've installed them in the past, you may find that they're missing after an Xcode upgrade.

In Xcode, go to Preferences -> Downloads and make sure "Command Line Tools" is installed. It's an extra 115MB download.